# Golang: Convert byte array to big.Int

Tags: go, rsa

I'm trying to create an RSA Public Key from a Modulus and Exponent stored in a byte array.  After some experimentation I've got the following:

```
func bytes_to_int(b []byte) (acc uint64) {
  length := len(b)
  if length % 4 != 0 {
    extra := (4 - length % 4)
    b = append([]byte(strings.Repeat("\000", extra)), b...)
    length += extra
  }
  var block uint32
  for i := 0; i < length; i += 4 {
    block = binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b[i:i+4])
    acc = (acc << 32) + uint64(block)
  }
return
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(bytes_to_int(data[:128]))
  fmt.Println(bytes_to_int(data[128:]))
}
```

This appears to work (although I'm not convinced there isn't a better way).  My next step was to convert it to use math/big in order to handle larger numbers.  I can see an Lsh function to do the << but can't figure out how to recursively add the Uint32(block) to the big.Int.

For reference, the Public Key I'm attempting to import is a Mixmaster Key stored in a keyring (pubring.mix):
http://www.mixmin.net/draft-sassaman-mixmaster-XX.html#key-format
http://pinger.mixmin.net/pubring.mix

Comment: `b = append(make([]byte, extra), b...)` should be more efficient than using `strings.Repeat`, good luck with the rest of the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want [Int.SetBytes](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes) to make a `big.int` from a slice of `[]byte`.

```
func (z *Int) SetBytes(buf []byte) *Int
```

`SetBytes` interprets `buf` as the bytes of a big-endian unsigned integer, sets `z` to that value, and returns `z`.

This should be quite straightforward to use in your application since your keys are in big-endian format according to the doc you linked.

Comment: Thanks Nick, just what I needed.  Worth noting that the big library also includes a Uint64 function that was useful for setting the Exponent(E) on an rsa.PublicKey which is an int.

Comment: What if I want to extract exponent and modulus from byte array in little endian format and then use them to create public key ?? Can you please tell how to achieve that??

Answer (score 12):

```
import "math/big"

z := new(big.Int)
z.SetBytes(byteSliceHere)
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Nick mentioned, you could use `SetBytes`, keep in mind the input is in base64 so you have to decode that first.

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/4Rm-g6IPXD):

```
func Base64ToInt(s string) (*big.Int, error) {
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    i := new(big.Int)
    i.SetBytes(data)
    return i, nil
}
```